# Reasons why a Google Voice number might be taken away

Tags: google-voice

I've been using GoogleVoice off and on for years, but have started using it more, and using it as my "main" number now. In the past, I've had more than a handful of GoogleVoice numbers, and at one point lost one as a result of not using it, and not checking the email account it was tied to for awhile; wasn't a big deal, and in fact, it was a good thing, since it led to my awareness that like email accounts, it's possible for them to be lost.

**What are reasons that a GoogleVoice number might be lost, and per reason, what if any actions should be taken to avoid them?**  For examples, might include, but are not limited to: unintentional-abuse, account-hacked, use-based-termination, reuse-of-"real", etc.

Ask the question in part, because while I have a pretty good idea of how a similar question about Gmail might be answered, I have no idea what I should expect from GoogleVoice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### If you read the [terms of service](http://www.google.com/googlevoice/program-policies.html) (which are very hard to find btw) it states what is prohibited:

> To uphold the quality and reputation of Google Voice, your use of
> Google Voice is subject to these program policies. If you are found to
> be in violation of our policies at any time, as determined by Google
> in its sole discretion, we may warn you or suspend or terminate your
> account.

- Place calls or offer to do the same with respect to any unlawful,
  defamatory, harassing, abusive, fraudulent, infringing, obscene, or
  otherwise objectionable content
- Enter forwarding phone numbers that are not under the direct control
  of the user
- Transmit content that may be harmful to minors
- Impersonate another person (via the use of a telephone number or
  otherwise) or otherwise misrepresent yourself or the source of any
  phone call
- Illegally transmit another's intellectual property or other
  proprietary information without such owner's or licensor's permission
- Use Google Voice to violate the legal rights (such as rights of
  privacy and publicity) of others
- Promote or encourage illegal activity
- Interfere with other Google Voice users' enjoyment of the Google
  Voice Service
- Create multiple user accounts in connection with any violation of the
  Agreement or create user accounts by automated means or under false
  or fraudulent pretenses
- Sell, trade, resell or otherwise exploit for any unauthorized
  commercial purpose or transfer any Google Voice account
- Modify, adapt, translate, or reverse engineer any portion of the
  Google Voice Service
- Remove any copyright, trademark or other proprietary rights notices
  contained in or on the Google Voice Service
- Reformat or frame any portion of the web pages that are part of the
  Google Voice Service

> Account Inactivity
>
> Google may reclaim your Google Voice number (if you have one) if you
> have not placed or received calls, sent or received text messages for
> a period of 9 months. We will not reclaim numbers that have been
> ported in to Google Voice or made permanent.

Answer (score 1):

Pure inactivity, as you noted, is probably the primary reason.

Comment: +1 @Scott Wilson: Guess I'm not looking for the primary, but any reason, though that might be hard to peg.